# Reading two files and printing same values in the new file in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read values from two files and write only the same values in the new(third) file. Is there any code or function I can use? What I have tried is that reading two files with `DO` statement and named them `variable1(i)`, `variable2(j)`, however I think comparing them is not easy for me, which is not working in the way of `variable1(i) = variable (j)`

Example:

file 1:

```
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,.........
f(a1),f(b1),f(c1),.......
```

Obviously I don't know the function, I just know the results.

file 2:

```
e2,e2,c1,c1,c1,c1,a2,a1,..........
```

new file 3:

```
f(e2),f(e2),f(c1),f(c1),f(c1),f(a2),f(a1)......
```

here's my code and the error is occurring because the number of data in two file is different

```
  real*8 refjd(64285),pha(64285)
  real*8 timejd(55436),epha(55436)
  real*8 phs

  format(47x,f10.2)
  open(4,file="neic56.out")
  do j=1,55436
  read(4,55)timejd(j)
  close(4)




  format(f10.2,1x,f8.4)
  open(3,file="74-17.out")
  do i=1,64285
  read(3,44)refjd(i),pha(i)
  close(3)
  end do

  if(timejd(j) .EQ. refjd(i)) then
  epha(j)=pha(i)
  phs=epha(j)/360.
  open(5,file="ejplphase.dat")
  write(5,66)phs
  end if
  format(f6.4)   



  end do
  end
```

Comment: Welcome, be sure to take the welcome [tour]. I have edited your question. I removed some unimportant noise and I improved the formatting, it is good to learn the formatting features of StackOverflow. We need to see your code, you should not just describe it using words, but you must show the actual code and describe what was wrong with it, what kind of problems or errors you got. See [ask] for more.

Comment: Be careful with opening an external file on unit `5`. Unit `5` is normally pre-connected to standard input (e.g. keyboard). Use numbers larger than 10.

Comment: you should read each file in its own loop, then have a seperate loop (nested i and j) for the comparison. As is you only check a single i value (64286) with your if statement

Answer (score 1):

A naive algorithm that would do the job is the following:

```
    program filesOut

    implicit none

    integer :: i, j
    real*8  :: refjd(64285), pha(64285)
    real*8  :: timejd(55436) 
    real*8  :: phs

100 format(47x,f10.2)
    open(15, file="neic56.out", status='old')
    do j=1,55436
       read(15,100) timejd(j)
    end do
    close(15)

200 format(f10.2,1x,f8.4)
    open(25,file="74-17.out", status='old')
    do i=1,64285
       read(25,200) refjd(i), pha(i)
    end do
    close(25)

300 format(f6.4)
    open(35,file="ejplphase.dat", status='unknown')

    outerloop: do i = 1, size(timejd)
       do j = 1, size(refjd)
          if (timejd(i) == refjd(j)) then
             phs = pha(j)/360.
             write(35,300) phs
             cycle outerloop
          end if
       end do
    end do outerloop
    close(35)
    end program
```

There are some improvements that could be made to increase the efficiency depending on the specifications of your problem.